# Filter by Date Range in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am trying to filter a List based on specified date range in a form but it's not filtering. The data remains the same. Thank you in advance for your help

This is what I have tried So far. My Controller:

```
public TransactionsVM transactions = new();

public IActionResult Transactions(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claims = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            transactions.AccountUser = _db.ApplicationUserRepo.GetOne(x => x.Id == claims.Value);
            transactions.BankAccount = _db.BankAccountRepo
                .GetOne(x => x.Id == transactions.AccountUser.BankAccountId);
            
            IEnumerable<Transactions> transList = _db.TransactionsRepo
                .GetAll().Where(x => x.BankAccountId == transactions.BankAccount.Id);

            if (StartDate != null)
            {
                transList = _db.TransactionsRepo
                 .GetAll().Where(x => x.BankAccountId == transactions.BankAccount.Id)
                 .Where(j => j.TransactionDate >= StartDate);
            }
            else if (StartDate != null && EndDate != null)
            {
                transList = _db.TransactionsRepo
                 .GetAll().Where(x => x.BankAccountId == transactions.BankAccount.Id)
                 .Where(j => j.TransactionDate >= StartDate && j.TransactionDate <= EndDate); ;
            }
```

The form in the Transactions view:

```
<form asp-action="Transactions">
                            <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="StartDate" class="my-form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="EndDate" class="my-form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2 my-auto">
                                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn bg-green text-light">Filter</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Hi, your "else if" will never be executed. In your case, try to rearrange you code to:
if else condition as first IF
if as if else (so you swap conditions)
and then add ELSE and put the code to get the translist..
IEnumerable<Transactions> transList = ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (StartDate != null){ //code A}
else if (StartDate != null && EndDate != null){ //code B}
```

There's a problem in this logic. 
If startdate exist, go code A ,so the following `else` will run only when startdate not exist，which means code B never gonna run. 
You should change `else if` to `if` to make all the conditions work seperately.

Comment: Thank you Jerry! I figured this.